# When I copy my instructor's website blocker code, why do I get a permission error even though his works and mine doesn't

Tags: python

So I am trying to code a website blocker. When I finished the code, I get a permission error. I am using a Windows computer. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong or help fix my problem? Thank you in advance.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt

hosts_path = r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
redirect = "127.0.0.1"
website_list = ["https://www.youtube.com/", "youtube.com"]
final_list = [redirect + " "+ i for i in website_list]
final_string_block = "\n".join(final_list)

while True:
if dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day, 8,) < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day,18):
    print("Within Time...")
    with open(hosts_path, "r+") as file:
        content = file.read()
        for website in website_list:
            if website in content:
                pass
            else:
                file.write(redirect+ ""+website+"\n")
else:
    with open(hosts_path, "r+") as file:
        content = file.readlines()
        file.seek(0)
        for line in content:
            if not any(website in line for website in website_list):
                file.write(line)
        file.truncate()
time.sleep(5)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\chris\.vscode\Realistic Programs\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 13, in <module>
    with open(hosts_path, "r+") as file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts'
```

Comment: The Permission denied is from Windows not from Python. The user you are logged in as does not have permission to access that file.

Answer (score 1):

Because the hosts file is applicable to all users you need administrative privileges to write to it. Try running python as administrator and you should be able to edit the file.

Comment: How do I run python as administrator?

Comment: The easiest way is to simply run the program from which you run the script as administrator, whether that is an IDE or cmd or powershell...